# Swift: Vertical scroll within horizontal scroll within vertical scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, instagram

I'm trying to create scrolling behaviour similar to Instagram's profile page, ie. a vertically scrolling view at the top (eg. name, avatar, etc.), and below that a grid of images that can pan left and right to reveal more sets of images, while also being able to vertically scroll.

For the record, I've read through tons of very similar posts to this, but I haven't found any that address the scrolling issue I bring up below.

[image]

This is the setup that I have so far:

[image]

Note: the width and height of the green scrollview is equal to that of the red one.

This setup gets me most of the way there, but if you swipe up and let go of the red scrollview it doesn't trigger the green scroll view to scroll. And conversely once the green scrollview has taken up the entire screen there's no way to get back to the red scrollview because its not triggered either.

I've had some success by enabling/disabling the green scrollview when the red scrollview scrolls past the height of the header, but its pretty janky.

```
  func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

     let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
     var isScrollingDown = translation.y > 0
     let offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

     if isScrollingDown, offset <= scrollHeight { //scrollHeight is equal to the height of the header cell
         greenScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
     }
     else if !isScrollingDown, offset >= scrollHeight {
         greenScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
     }
 }
```

Is this solution heading in the right direction, or is there a better way to accomplish this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this for awhile. I came across this and it has worked very well.

https://github.com/OfTheWolf/TwitterProfile

Comment: Amazing! I've been searching for days for something like this. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I created a repo that I believe is the same (that also supports autolayout) as the example Harrison Senesac gave, except my repo only has the horizontal scrolling part, for now. It’s intended to be a library unlike the example Harrison gave (which won’t work well with a NavigationController or bottom TabBar since its UIScrollView uses frames, whereas mine uses autolayout).

https://github.com/YoomamaFTW/infinite-view-controllers

Basically, for future users, the main point is to use the UIScrollBar that seems like a PageController. Each “page” is just a view controller that you add to the UIScrollBar while increasing the content size’s width.

I’ve implemented some features (like the collection view that shows the two images and a line in the gif that you added), but those will be added on Saturday since I didn’t get the time to add it to both my app and the repo.